# C++ - Global Variable within Multiple Files

Tags: c++, global-variables

I defined variable 'a' in the **header.h** and use it in **test1.cpp**, **test2.cpp**.
When I build it, i got a link error like

**fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found**

What's the problem?
I want to use global variable 'a' can be used in multiple cpp.

header.h

```
int a = 0;
```

main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
#include "test1.h"
#include "test2.h"

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    test1();    // expected output : 0
    test1();    // expected output : 1
    test2();    // expected output : 2
    test2();    // expected output : 3

    cout << "in main : " << a << endl;    // expected output : 3

    return 0;
}
```

test1.h

```
extern int a;

void test1();
```

test1.cpp

```
#include "test1.h"
#include "header.h"

void test1() {
    cout << "test1 : " << a << endl;
    a++;
}
```

test2.h

```
extern int a;

void test2();
```

test2.cpp

```
#include "test2.h"
#include "header.h"

void test2() {
    cout << "test2 : " << a << endl;
    a++;
}
```

Comment: Post the compiler options, logs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should only be putting the `extern` declaration in *one* header file. This header file should then be included by any other file that wants to use `a`.

Then you should place the definition `int a = 0;` in *one* implementation file (a `.cpp` file).

At the moment, you have many `extern` declarations in multiple header files, which is *okay* but just confusing. You should simply declare it in one place. However, the main problem you have is that you are *defining* `a` in `header.h`. If you include that header in multiple translation units, you will have multiple definitions.

Comment: And better replace this global altogether with proper function parameters transfers.

Comment: I want that test1 and test2 don't know each other.

Comment: @user1285975 If you don't want these modules to know each other, your architecture is logically incorrect. In that case, you have to put the declaration and definition into a new third module, which is known by both test1 and test2.

Comment: Oh I've got it. It's so foolish. Thank you.